# Connection Django to MySql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've created a new database. After that I created a new user and password

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

then to grant all access to the database

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But then I run **python manage.py runserver**  I got File

```
"/home/y700/Env/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'new_user'@'localhost' to database 'my_db'")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost';`?

Comment: @dirkgroten I wasn't being attentive. You're right, thank you!